# MongoDB Save Regular Expressions like email address, username

Tags: mongodb

How to save regular expression patterns in mongodb.

**Example**: Email address pattern

**/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/** (email address),

**Example**: User name pattern

**/[A-Za-z0-9-\@.,_]{6,50}/ (user name).**

Here i validated for user type, in the same way i need to validate email address based on the pattern .

```
{
    "_id" : "Validation_rule",
    "flowId" : "String",
    "lineOfBusiness" : "String",
    "description" : "Invalid User type.It should be either of 'Admin', 'enduser'",
    "spelExprRecord" : {
        "className" : "com.my.Account.User",
        "booleanSpelExpression" : "(role.equalsIgnoreCase('admin') == true) || (role.equalsIgnoreCase('enduser') == true) "
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. You wish to enforce certain patterns for document fields?

Comment: yes Robert @RobertMoskal

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample collection created with validator. A document will be inserted / updated only if the 3 three conditions specified in the validators are satisfied

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   { validator: { $and:
      [
         { phone: { $type: "string" } },
         { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
         { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
      ]
   }
} )
```