# Removing documents not having @ in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, email

I am created a mongodb and in the I am filling my client email addresses and there related accounts. But I have found that some values listed as email are not email at all. See the below example.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591d9cf30ef9acde11d7af6b"),
        "email" : "w@Yahoo.com",
        "src" : [
                {
                        "acc" : "yahoo",
                        "name" : "matter"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591daa540ef9acde11d7af6c"),
        "email" : "122",
        "src" : [
                {
                        "acc" : "ldd"
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to check if the key `email` has the correct value of email or not. If not then I would like to remove the document and make my mongo clean.
How I can achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066324/mongodb-save-regular-expressions-like-email-address-username might help you to some extent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the remove command using a regex with the `$not` operator

`db.getCollection('somecollection').remove( { email: { $not: /@/ } } )`

I'm not 100% sure the regex will work correctly with the `@` like this. but I would recommend to always test by using `find` in stead of `remove` first.

`db.getCollection('somecollection').find( { email: { $not: /@/ } } )`

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: I think the regex must also have `.`, so that if the email entered is something like this `gg@mail` then still it is not email address

Comment: if you want to check the validity of an email I would recommend googling for a regex for that purpose. But since the question only stated to check for @ I answered that. Anyway, a best practice solution would involve checking before entering into the DB in the first place, but that is a different story..

Comment: Got it.. bro.. Thank you for your answer